# Values not storing....sessions..cookies and localstorage

Tags: php, javascript, html

I made a fiddle with my code and I am using sessions to memorize the URL and local storage to store the values I am putting in. The problem here is that after 2 days of not touching the file I found the session values were "emptied" so I am guessing destroyed. I am not sure if the same happened to the localstorage. I know sessions are cookies not made to last long so I will need to figure out cookies and use those any ideas on that would help. Anyone know if localstorage has a time limit as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/16/

Comment: Please try to rephrase what you were trying to say, it's really unclear what is the intended result. What data, how much, do you want to use PHP or JS to set the cookies etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session wasn't "emptied". It most likely expired, as per the [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), and cleaned up by the session garbage collector.

If you want to use long-duration persistent sessions, you'll have to disable the session cleanup functionality, or set a longer expiry time.

Comment: Marc thanks a lot, how can I disable the cleaner or set the expiry time? Is it possible to have a session that never expires?

Comment: do you know if local storage has an expiry date by default?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's persistent by default, and only goes away if/when the original script deletes things, or the browser empties the storage.